# Unable to hit https for certain projects

Tags: apache, xampp, ssl-certificate, port, virtualhost

I have a project in xampp/htdocs/project1

I needed to create another project so I decided to assign them different ports so now,
xampp/htdocs/project1 runs on 8080

and my project2 which is under
C:/release/project2 runs on 7171

I needed to make project2 https , so created ssl certificate and everything is setup in apache too.(listening to 443)

https:/xx.xx.xx.xxx:443/project1/login.php gave error 
whereas https:/xx.xx.xx.xxx:443/project2/login.php could be hit.

so i did following change in httpd-ssl.conf, 
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" to DocumentRoot "C:/release"

but now i get the error -

```
 Access forbidden!

 You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
 read-protected or not readable by the server.

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
 Error 403
```

This error is given for both,
https:/xx.xx.xx.xxx:443/project1/login.php
and https:/xx.xx.xx.xxx:443/project2/login.php

I thought it was permission problems, but i can still hit these
https:/xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/project1/login.php
and https:/xx.xx.xx.xxx:7171/project2/login.php

What could be the problem? I am new to website development so could not figure out what I am doing wrong.Is project being under htdocs compulsory for this or assigning of different ports was wrong?

Comment: I already have
<Directory "C:/release">
 AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
in httpd-vhosts.conf
Still cant figure out why its giving permission error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have got it working by now,

But It seems like the permissions are not set.
It is not compulsary to have the project under htdocs.Since your project is working on 7171 everything might be fine.
you can try following,

1) for permissions, Check if you have  AllowOverride All Order allow,deny Allow from all  set in httpd.conf too.Restart the server.

If it still doesnt work,
2) check if http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUAKLUZa-AU can help.